# How To Create An Array of Movie Clip with number

Tags: actionscript-3, for-loop

I have multi movieclips in my stage and they have instanceName e.g. k1,k2,... . I want to create`ar=[k1,k2,k3,k4, ...]`.

```
var i: int;
var ar: Array = new Array();

for (i = 1; i < 5; i++)
{
    ar[i-1] = ["k" + i];
}
trace(ar);
ar[1].x = 100;
```

But the end of code does not perform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is to create an array of MovieClips, but instead of it you create an array of Arrays of Strings. To achieve your goal, you need to find an instance of a clip on stage by its name. Here is how you can try to do that:

```
const array:Array = new Array();
for(var i:int = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    const childName:String = "k" + (i + 1);
    const myMovieClip:MovieClip = stage.getChildByName(childName) as MovieClip;
    array.push(myMovieClip);
}
```

Comment: Thx, I want to do is to create an array of MovieClips.Show error : **TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference**. why `const` instead of `var`? by this way your code is Ok!. please edit that.

Comment: The "const" is only because of style - it shows that this value will not change . There is no difference for you what to use here.

Comment: I mean `const `to `var` in loop!.

Comment: @SAt as I said before, in this example there is no difference what to use, const or var. Please take a look at this example: http://wonderfl.net/c/WiQg